# How do you automatically serialize and load an Ember Data object from a JSON response?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a UserSession model defined as such:

```
App.UserSession = DS.Model.extend({
  authToken: attr('string'),
  firstName: attr('string'),
  lastName: attr('string')
});
```

When a user is logging in, I'm making an AJAX POST request to my back-end which return a JSON representation such as:

```
{
  "user_session": {
    "id": 1,
    "auth_token": "token_here",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Now normally, if I were to do the following, Ember Data would take care of automatically serializing the JSON and adding the object:

```
App.UserSession.find(<session-id>);
```

When I'm making a manual AJAX call though, is there an easy way to load the JSON returned into an Ember Data store object without having to manually deserialize it?

**Edited for clarity:**

The below **does not** work, but I'm hoping to find some function that does what's described above, which may look similar to the call below.

```
App.UserSession.load(<session-json>);
```

Comment: I think it wouldn't work because your JSON doesn't have an `id` property.

Comment: Forgot to include "id", but it's definitely present.  .load() doesn't work, I'm just trying to find something that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the latest version (11) of ember-data there is a breaking change for loading data.

> **Loading Data**
>
> Previously, some features of the store, such as load(), assumed a
>   single adapter.
>
> If you want to load data from your backend without the application
>   asking for it (for example, through a WebSockets stream), use this
>   API:
>
> ```
> store.adapterForType(App.Person).load(store, App.Person, payload);
> ```
>
> This API will also handle sideloaded and embedded data. We plan to add
>   a more convenient version of this API in the future.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#loading-data

You're going to want to grab the instance of your store. If you're in a controller you can do:

```
@get('store')
```

You can also do:

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
```

which isn't recommended as it's using the internal API (noted by the __ surrounding the container call) which isn't guaranteed to not change.

Once you have your instance of the store you can load in your UserSession:

```
@get('store').adapterForType(App.UserSession).load(@get('store'), App.UserSession, sessionJson['user_session']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is outdated, but the concept is still the same.

I believe the correct way to handle this is with `this.get('store').pushPayload({data: ...})`