# Ember Websocket...can't find any records?

Tags: ember.js, socket.io

So, I'm stuck not being able to bring in arrays from my livestream websocket, which is coming through as JSON.

Not seeing any records in ember inspector, but plenty is printing out with console.log(data). Getting error:

```
-94 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`
```

(but there is an ID included in each livestream update).

**Here's the code: http://jsbin.com/qapik/1/edit?html,js,output**

JSON looks like...

```
{
    "group":{
        "usage":{
            "case1":0,
            "case2":0,
            "case3":0
        },
        "sunshine":"00/00/0000",
        "id":1010,
        "device_info":11.5,
    }
}
```

With the console showing updates...

```
Tue Apr 01 2014 09:22:09 GMT-0400 (EDT): group update: {"group": ...
```

At the end of the day, I want to show {{#each}} {{device_info}}... and more.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Edit - Solution:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {                
        var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:8887');                                                           
        var self = this;                                                                                                   

        socket.on('group_live_stream', function(data){                                                                               
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(data); // data happens to be a JSON string
            self.store.push('group',dataObj.group);                                                                              
        });                                                                                                                
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects pushed onto the store should be formatted like in the example here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

```
{
    "usage":{
        "case1":0,
        "case2":0,
        "case3":0

    },
    "sunshine":"00/00/0000",
    "id":1010,
    "device_info":11.5
}
```

In other words, when you're pushing it onto the store, the object should not be wrapped in `group`. This is notably different than how Ember Data expects JSON responses using it's REST adapter (when ED gets a group record, it does indeed expect an object like `{group:{...}}`).

Comment: Ahh - I see. That makes sense why it's not working then. Is there a "simple" way to normalize the object?

Comment: Is `that.store.push('Group',data.group);` what you're asking for?

Comment: That only brings forth: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" unfortunately.

Comment: what exactly does the object `data` look like? (what is output when you `console.log(data);`?) it was hard to be sure exactly the format of the object since your original question was missing some brackets.

Comment: So, if you `console.log(data.group);`, presumably you get a nice group object which has an `id`, right? If so, then it seems like you're giving Ember Data what it wants. But looking closer at your jsbin, you are using both Ember-Data and Ember-Restless? I'm not sure you can do that. All my advice has been for Ember-Data v1.0.0-beta.7. Unless you really need it for some reason, try removing the Ember-Restless stuff and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hmm... console.log(data.group); only produces the same error:

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. 

I updated jsbin - the Restless stuff was leftover from something else I tried. Deleted that with no change, unfortunately. Thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: So what does `console.log(data.group)` return? The error can't be from that call, must be from the .push that follows. Are you sure that data is the object you think it is, as shown by console.log(data)?

Comment: I see what you mean - `console.log(data.group)` produces "undefined" with a steadily rising number. `console.log(data)` produces a nice stream of my JSON from above. There's some core concept I'm just missing here...

Comment: hmmm. maybe data isn't actually a js object and is for some reason a string or something? try `console.log(typeof data)`. If you find out it's a string, you'll need to do `dataObj = JSON.parse(data)` to get a js object

Comment: looks like a "string". Hopefully that gets me on the right (new) path!

Comment: Got it right - or, can now see in ember data inspector. Code added above. For some reason the records won't display on the template, though.

Comment: Hah - last question. Why wouldn't {{#each controller}} {{device_info}} {{/each}} not work on my template?

Comment: To clarify, this really has nothing to do with websockets, since what you're asking about now comes from the model hook, but... Does `{{#each}} {{device_info}} {{/each}}` work any better? If not, confirm that `data.data.groups.map(...` returns an array with length > 0. Also, why are you using a map? That statement as you have it in your jsbin should be equivalent to just doing `return data.data.groups`